# Is gay marriage prohibited?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, homosexuality

Is there anything explicitly prohibiting gay marriage in Islam?

I don't mean sodomy or gay adultery. I mean actual marriage and raising a family as a homosexual couple.

Sura 4, An-Nisa appears to specifically prohibit marrying sisters, mothers, and so on, but does not mention brothers or men.

Ash-Shu'ara 26:165-166 is the story of Lot and brings up having sex with the men when they were offered wives. But this sounds more like extreme adultery rather than a ban on sodomy.

My Arabic is very poor so I rely on translations for understanding. Can someone clarify this?

Comment: @bummi I don't think this is a duplicate of that. I understand this question to be asking whether Islam permits _religious_ gay marriage where (I guess) the partners abstain from sexual relations.

Answer (score -1):

The Qur'an specifies to "**Marry women** of your choice in 2s, 3s, or 4s, but if you cannot do justice between them, then marry only one." - by this statement we can say that gay marriage cannot take place within Islam:)

Comment: Surah Nisa Verse3

Comment: So lesbian marriage is okay then? Because that's just women marrying women.

Answer (score -2):

Islam is very clear on gay marriage just like its clear on marrying your foster brothers step mum. Wait, there is no quran that says that? But does that make it ok? We don't just rely on quran to come up with an answer. Do you think the hundred thousand scholars over 1400 years were all stupid?

Brother it doesn't have to be in the quran. Someone like shafii who was a genius and had strong arabic would have made his mazhab allow gay marriage if he believed there was no evidence to make it haraam. But for him it was very clear that it is haraam, and every other scholar too. Even marriage to other animals and creatures (they would have considered these options for inheritance).